# Independence of Random Variables

Tags: probability

- If $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables so are also the random variables $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ for $f$ and $g$ measurable and bounded functions.

  The independence of $X$ and $Y$ implies:
  $\Bbb{E}(f(X)g(Y)) = \Bbb{E}(f(X))\Bbb{E}(g(Y))$.

  I don't see how the independence of $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ follows from there.
- I also would like to see why the complements of $X$ and $Y$ will also be independent.

Thanks for any comment.

Comment: *Hint*. Notice that the $\sigma$-algebras satisfy $\sigma(f(X)) \subseteq \sigma(X)$ and $\sigma(g(Y)) \subseteq \sigma(Y)$. Also, what is the complement of a *random variable*?

Comment: Are you saying you don't know why the independence of $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ follow from your equation $E(f(X)g(Y)) = E(f(X))E(g(Y))$ ?

Comment: Yes. I don't see why the Independence of f(X) and g(Y) follows. The equation i wrote follows from the Independence of X and Y.

Comment: @SangchulLee 'complement of a random variable' ? What is that?

Comment: @BCLC, I don't know. I am literally asking it to the OP.

Comment: @SangchulLee Oh lol sorry didn't see that hehehe

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\E}{\operatorname{E}}$The independence of $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ **does not** follow from the fact that $\E(f(X)g(Y))$ $= \E(f(X))\E(g(Y))$.  That last fact would imply that $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ are uncorrelated, provided that $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ have finite variances.  So you have
$$
\text{independence of }f(X)\text{ and }g(Y)\text{ entails } \E(f(X)g(Y))= \E(f(X))\E(g(Y))
$$
and
$$
\E(f(X)g(Y))= \E(f(X))\E(g(Y)) \text{ does not entail independence of }f(X)\text{ and }g(Y).
$$

The way in which $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ are proved to be independent is this.  One must show that the events
$$
[f(X)\in A],\qquad [g(Y)\in B] \tag 1
$$
are independent for every pair of measurable sets $A$ and $B$.  That is what independence of random variables is.  Now recall that
$f^{-1}[A] = \{x\in\mathbb R: f(x)\in A\}$ and $g^{-1}[B] = \{x\in\mathbb R: g(x)\in B\}$.  (It doesn't matter here that $f$ and $g$ may fail to be one-to-one so that no inverse functions $f^{-1}$ and $g^{-1}$ exist; this is simply a definition of what the notation $f^{-1}[A]$ means.  Observe that $f(X)\in A$ if and only if $X\in f^{-1}[A]$, and similarly for $g$.  And the events
$$
X\in f^{-1}[A],\quad Y\in g^{-1}[B] \tag 2
$$
are independent because independence of the two reandom variables implies that.  Now observe that the two events in $(2)$, reported here to be independent, are the same events that appear in $(1)$.  Therefore the events in $(1)$ are independent.  And this holds for EVERY pair of sets $A$ and $B$.  Hence $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ are independent.

As for complements: I know what the complement of an event is; I don't know what the complement of a random variable is.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. If X and Y are now considered as events one might define indicator functions on these events and per definition we call these functions as r.v. ( they are measurable ).

Comment: Would you explain what do you mean with the expressions in (1), it's a question of notation. Do the events belong to A ( at the first expression )or to the sigma-algebra on which f is defined ? Thanks.

Comment: The set $A$ is not an event, i.e. not a subset of the probability space, but rather is a subset of the real line $\mathbb R$.  The event $[f(X)\in A]$ is a subset of the probability space; if you like you can write it as $\{\omega\in\Omega : f(X(\omega))\in A\}$.  It's as if $\Omega$ is a population and $\omega$ is a randomly chosen member of the population and $X(\omega)$ may be that member's income and $Y(\omega)$ may be that member's SAT score. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I have a last question.  At (2) do you mean by X the image under X or un element of the probability space ?

Comment: @ivo : I don't understand your last question.  $X$ is a random variable: it assigns a number to each possible randomly chosen outcome.  The event $X\in f^{-1}[A]$ is not a member of the probability space but rather a subset of the probability space; it is $\{\omega\in\Omega : f(X(\omega))\in A\}$. ${}\qquad{}$